# running a UWP test project in azure devops fails due to missing AppxManifest under ilc folder

Tags: uwp, azure-devops

​Hi

I am using `windows-2019` agent with this step:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: Run UnitTests
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **/Release/x64/UnitTests.build.appxrecipe
    searchFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
```

in the log, I can see it's launching the test with something like this:

```
 vstest.console.exe "D:\a\1\drop\Release\x64\UnitTests.build.appxrecipe"
```

Next, it fails with this error:

[error]Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\a\1\s\drop\Release\x64\ilc\AppxManifest.xml'.  ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

I am not sure why it is happening, because in my local machine, I can run `vstest.console.exe` against the appxreceipt that is built from my local environment.

I do not have the **ilc** subfolder locally. The AppxManifest.xml is actually in the same folder as the appxrecipe file, why is Azure Devops looking for it in a subfolder?

The unit test runs and passes locally, but just can't run in azure devops.
Anyone knows about this error message?
Thanks

---

**Update**

Later I copied from another folder, so now the test run folder has a `ilc` subfolder with the AppxManifest.xml. I printed the entire directory tree and I can see the file.

Unfortunately, I am still seeing the error:

```
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4168648Z ##[error]Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\a\1\s\drop\Release\x86\UnitTests\ilc\AppxManifest.xml'.
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4171040Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Failed to launch testhost with error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\a\1\s\drop\Release\x86\UnitTests\ilc\AppxManifest.xml'.
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4179397Z ##[error]   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4180905Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4183043Z ##[error]   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4184829Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4187337Z ##[error]   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4188735Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4191848Z ##[error]   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4193331Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4199669Z ##[error]   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4201095Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4203263Z ##[error]   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4204425Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4212719Z ##[error]   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4214161Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4219038Z ##[error]   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4220367Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4223912Z ##[error]   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4225961Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4227028Z ##[error]   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4228461Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4229380Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.AppxManifestFile.ReadTargetPlatformVersions()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4230291Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.AppxManifestFile.ReadTargetPlatformVersions()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4231242Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.AppxManifestFile.get_TargetPlatformVersion()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4232033Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.AppxManifestFile.get_TargetPlatformVersion()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4232939Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.RecipeFile.get_TargetPlatformVersion()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4233716Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.RecipeFile.get_TargetPlatformVersion()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4234953Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.Deployer.Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.IDeployer.get_TargetPlatformVersion()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4235974Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.Deployer.Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.IDeployer.get_TargetPlatformVersion()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4236919Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.UwpTestHostManager.<LaunchHostAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4237698Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.UwpTestHostManager.<LaunchHostAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4238493Z ##[error]--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4239155Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4239936Z ##[error]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4240675Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4241737Z ##[error]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4242520Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4243715Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.UwpTestHostManager.<Microsoft-VisualStudio-TestPlatform-ObjectModel-Host-ITestRuntimeProvider-LaunchTestHostAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4244732Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.UwpTestHostRuntimeProvider.UwpTestHostManager.<Microsoft-VisualStudio-TestPlatform-ObjectModel-Host-ITestRuntimeProvider-LaunchTestHostAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
2021-01-04T18:02:16.4245637Z ##[error]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Hi @sowen. You could refer to the answer and try to change the pipeline definition. If this issue still exists, you could share your build definition with us.

Answer (score 1):

> vstest.console.exe "D:\a\1\drop\Release\x64\UnitTests.build.appxrecipe"

The VSTest task is executing the unit test in the Build Artifacts folder.

Based on my test,  AppxManifest.xml will not be pushed to the artifacts folder  after build step, it will exist in the `source directory -> bin` folder (same folder as the appxrecipe file).

[image]

So you could try to change the `searchFolder` as `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.

Here is my yaml sample:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x86|x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  appxPackageDir: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    platform: 'x86'
    solution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(buildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(appxPackageDir)" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: 'x86|x64'
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\Release\UnitTestProject1.build.appxrecipe
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

Comment: interesting, I printed the entire tree of the folder but I didn't see that file. I have a strange issue, the pipeline is actually a multi-stage: the 1st stage was building the project with vs2017-win2016, if using windows-2019 complains platform toolset 141 is missing, but vs2017 can build it. But I can't run test in 2017, it complains the OS version being too old, coz the app has a min-version requirement. So I decide using windows-2019 to run test, after publishing and downloading the artifacts. I will get back to you sometime next week. thanks

Comment: Feel free to let me know if it could work.  Thanks.

Comment: On the other hand, when you upload the artifacts in stage 1, you could try to upload the sources directory(build.sourcesdirectory) as the artifacts. Then you could download the files in the next stage and check if it could work.

Comment: I now can see the file after copying, but I am still having the same error. I start feeling it's actually due to another reason...

Comment: Hi @sowen. Can you share your build definition with us? You could check if you run the VSTest task in the correct folder(ilc folder contains the AppxManifest file).

Comment: Hi @Kevin, can you look at this post? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1298837/running-a-uwp-test-project-in-devops-fails-due-to.html  I attached the log in there. I am happy to share the build definition too, but I can only upload in there if needed.